# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, sqlite3

**bot.py**

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
from random import randint
from db import UsersInfo as user
import time

def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')

    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '217945916')

    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():

            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                text = event.obj.text
                user_id = event.obj.from_id
                if event.obj.peer_id < 1:
                    if user.is_reg(user_id) == True:
                        if text.lower() == "начать":
                            user.insert(user_id)
                            keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time = False, inline = False)
                            keyboard.add_button(label = 'Клик ', color = VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
                            keyboard.add_line()
                            keyboard.add_button(label = 'Топ игроков ', color = VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
                            keyboard.add_line()
                            keyboard.add_button(label = 'Помощь ', color = VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE) 
                            vk.messages.send(user_id = user_id,
                            random_id = get_random_id(),
                            keyboard = keyboard.get_keyboard(),
                            message = "Вы зарегистирировались в чат-игре Кликер \nКликайте на кнопку 'Клик' и зарабатывайте очки \n\nДля просмотра топа игроков по кликам нажмите кнопку 'Топ игроков' \n\nЕсли нужна помощь используйте команду 'помощь' \n\nПриятной игры ")

                    else:
                        if text.lower() == "помощь" or text == "Помощь ":
                            vk.messages.send(user_id = user_id,
                            random_id = get_random_id(),
                            message = "Чат-игра кликер - игра, суть которой заключается в наборе очков топа благодаря кликам на главную кнопку \n\nЕсли у вас пропала клавиатура напишите любое сообщение, которое не похоже на команды ")
                        
                        elif text.lower() == "клик" or text == "Клик ":
                            point = randint(1, 3)
                            vk.messages.send(user_id = user_id,
                            random_id = get_random_id(),
                            message = f"Вы кликнули и получили +{point} {'очко' if point == 1 else 'очка'} топа ")
                            user.update(user_id, user.get_clicks(user_id) + point)

                        elif text.lower() == "топ игроков" or text == "Топ игроков ":
                            if user.rows() <= 15:
                                mes_text = "Топ игроков по кликам \n\n"
                                top = user.get_top(user.rows())
                                data = vk.users.get(user_ids = ", ".join([str(i[0]) for i in top]))
                                for i, value in enumerate(top):
                                    name = data[i]["first_name"]
                                    family = data[i]["last_name"]
                                    mes_text += f"- {name} {family} [{value[1]} шт.] \n" 

                                mes_text += "\nКликайте больше и возвышайтесь в топы "
                                vk.messages.send(user_id = user_id,
                                random_id = get_random_id(),
                                message = mes_text)
                            else:
                                mes_text = "Топ-15 игроков по кликам \n\n"
                                top = user.get_top(15)
                                data = vk.users.get(user_ids = ", ".join([str(i[0]) for i in top]))
                                for i, value in enumerate(top):
                                    name = data[i]["first_name"]
                                    family = data[i]["last_name"]
                                    mes_text += f"- {name} {family} [{value[1]} шт.] \n" 

                                mes_text += "\nКликайте больше и возвышайтесь в топы "
                                vk.messages.send(user_id = user_id,
                                random_id = get_random_id(),
                                message = mes_text)
                        else:
                            keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time = False, inline = False)
                            keyboard.add_button(label = 'Клик ', color = VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
                            keyboard.add_line()
                            keyboard.add_button(label = 'Топ игроков ', color = VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
                            keyboard.add_line()
                            keyboard.add_button(label = 'Помощь ', color = VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE) 
                            vk.messages.send(user_id = user_id,
                            random_id = get_random_id(),
                            message = "Неизвестная команда \n\n\nКлавиатура отправлена ✅")

    except TimeoutError:
            print("--------------- [ СЕТЕВАЯ ОШИБКА ] ---------------")
            print("Переподключение к серверам...")
            time.sleep(3)                                                   

                

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**db.py**

```py
import sqlite3 as sql

con = sql.connect('users.db')

with con:
    db = con.cursor()
    db.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users`
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0, 
        vk_id STRING,
        clicks INTEGER DEFAULT 0)
        """)
    con.commit()

class UsersInfo:

    def rows():
        db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'users'")
        con.commit()
        values = db.fetchone()
        return int(values[0])

    def is_reg(user_vk_id):
        db.execute(f"SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE vk_id= '{user_vk_id}'")
        con.commit()
        values = db.fetchone()
        if values is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def insert(user_vk_id):
        db.execute(f"INSERT INTO 'users' (vk_id) VALUES (?)", (user_vk_id,))
        con.commit()   

    def get_clicks(user_vk_id):
        db.execute(f"SELECT clicks FROM 'users' WHERE vk_id= '{user_vk_id}'")
        con.commit()
        values = db.fetchone()
        return values[0]

    def update(user_vk_id, clicks):
        db.execute(f"UPDATE 'users' SET clicks = {clicks} WHERE vk_id = {user_vk_id}")
        con.commit()   

    def get_top(count):
        db.execute(f"SELECT vk_id, clicks FROM 'users' ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT {count}")
        con.commit()
        values = db.fetchall()
        return values
```

ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\Desktop\VK_clicker_bot-main_zip\VK_clicker_bot-main.zip\bot.py", line 97, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Максимка\Desktop\VK_clicker_bot-main_zip\VK_clicker_bot-main.zip\bot.py", line 23, in main
    if event.obj.peer_id < 1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: У вас в ошибке речь идёт о каком то модуле "bot.py", а вы нам предоставили модули (main.py и db.py), зачем?